# Return a value coming directly from a function call vs. an intermediate variable

Tags: python

I have a function f(x), which does something and return values (a tuple).

I have another function that call this function , after processing parameters (the whole function operation is irrelevant to the question); and now I would like to know if there are evil intent in returning the function itself, vs runt the function, dump the output in a variable and return the variable.

A variable has a cost, and assign a value to a variable has a cost; but beside that, is there any sorcery that would happen behind the scene, that would make one better than the other ?

```
def myfunction(self):
    [do something]
    return f(x)
```

is the same as

```
def myfunction(self):
    [do something]
    b = f(x)
    return b
```

or one is to prefer to the other (and why)? I am talking purely on the OOP persepctive; without considering that create variables and assign has a cost, in terms of memory and CPU cycles.

Comment: There is no relevant 'cost' associated with the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't return the function. Returning the function would look like `return f`. You're returning the result of the function call. Generally speaking, the only reason to save that result before returning it is if you plan to do some other kind of processing on it before the return, in which case it's faster to just refer to a saved value rather than recomputing it. Another reason to save it would be for clarity, turning what might be a long one-liner with extensive chaining into several steps.

There's a possibility that those two functions might produce different results if you have some kind of asynchronous process that modifies your data in the background between saving the reference and returning it, but that's something you'll have to keep in mind based on your program's situation.

In a nutshell, save it if you want to refer to it, or just return it directly otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the incorrect statement; I meant to return the output of the function, not the function itself. So there could be cases when returning the function output without intermediate variable could cause problems; I am thinking about complex functions that call other functions in other modules and so on. If there is some sort of async operation, that would affect the returned value?

Comment: If you're assigning the value to a reference and then immediately returning it, there's almost no time for something to happen in between those events, because assigning a reference and returning a reference or value are very fast. You would also have to be doing something with threading or multiprocessing or multiple machines (e.g. the Internet). It's just barely possible that something could change. All I'm saying is that it's not impossible to get different results between those two methods. However, I wouldn't worry about it at this point. Just `return f(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Those are practically identical; use whichever one you think is more readable. If the performance of once versus the other actually matters for you, perhaps Python is not the best choice ;).

Comment: Thanks. Performance is not necessarily an issue, but coming from C, it is a habit to try to minimize calls to the minimum required.

Answer (score 0):

The cost difference between these is utterly negligible: in the worst case, one extra dictionary store, one extra dictionary lookup and one extra string in memory. In practice it won't even be that bad, since cpython stores local variables in a C array, so it's more like two c level pointer indirections.

As a matter of style, I would usually avoid the unnecessary variable but its possible that it might be better in particular cases. As a guideline, think about things like whether the amalgamated version leads to an excessively long line of code, whether the extra variable has a better name than eg `result`, and how clear it is that that function call is the result you need (and if it isnt, whether/how much a variable helps).

Comment: So it is purely a matter of style to not use intermediate variables unless needed, even if they improve readability? Not everyone write clear function names, which may cause confusion about what that function returns, versus the actual variable that says exactly what it contains.

Comment: @newbiez whether the variable improves readability is *exactly* a style issue, rather than a performance issue.

Comment: But in practice, I think that cases where the extra variable improves the clarity significantly will be quite rare. If it isn't obvious that that function call does exactly the work you need to do, you probably need a comment, and might even consider refactoring.